# Redux-Observable breaks on server-side rendering

Tags: node.js, webpack, redux, rxjs, redux-observable

I have a [test repo with redux-observable](https://github.com/Tomekmularczyk/react-starter/tree/with-rxjs)

It works with `webpack-dev-server` but breaks with `server-side-rendering` giving:

`TypeError: action$.ofType(...).delay is not a function`

**How to reproduce:**

`yarn dev` works okay (webpack-dev-server).

`yarn build && yarn start` - runs node server-side-rendering which is breaking when creating store with redux `createStore` method.

It recognizes imported operators from `rxjs` within a browser (webpack-dev-server). My guess it might be a problem with webpack `serverConfig`, more specifically with:

```
  externals: fs.readdirSync('./node_modules').concat([
    'react-dom/server',
  ]).reduce((ext, mod) => {
    ext[mod] = `commonjs ${mod}`;
    return ext;
  }, {}),
```

Answer (score 1):

importing the whole `rxjs` library will jeopardise your tree shaking.

use `pipe` instead.

```js
import { delay } from 'rxjs/operators';

const epic = action$ => action$
  .ofType('baz')
  .pipe(delay(5000))
  .mapTo({ type: 'bar' });
;
```

Answer (score 0):

It turned out I had to include `rxjs` in server.js where `express` is like:

```
import `rxjs`;
```

But I would swear I tried that solution before I posting a question.